# What command can parse out letters and digits within a character variable?

Tags: r, regex

I have a character (string) object in R that contains both digits and letters. When viewed in R environment it returns as:

```
 [1] " Sample Size =   955"
 [2] " Importance      0.861"
 [3] " Value      0.475 "
```

There are many more lines in this object, but that's the format. Essentially every line starts and ends with double quotations " some text with digits inside " but all of these data are within one R object that is character. 
What i want to have is to extract only the digits out of this object. So with the example above, I'd like to get another object, say, z that contains only 955, 0.861, 0.475. Similarly, is there a function that extracts only the text from each line? So I would get an object, y that contains Sample Size, Importance, Value?

**data**

```
x <- c(" Sample Size =   955", " Importance      0.861", " Value      0.475 ")
```

Comment: maybe? `regmatches(x, regexpr("[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?", x))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expression to solve this problem. Here a possible solution based in your example:

```
library(stringr)
vec <- c(" Sample Size =   955", " Importance      0.861", " Value      0.475 ")

str_extract(string = vec, pattern = "[0-9]{1,}(\\.)?[0-9]{0,}")
[1] "955"   "0.861" "0.475"
str_extract(string = vec, pattern = "[a-zA-Z]{1,}(\\s)?[a-zA-Z]{1,}")
[1] "Sample Size" "Importance"  "Value"
```

The first rule will look for a number with 1 or more digits followed, by a possible `.` and another possible number of 0 or more digits.
Similarly the second rule will look for a string with 1 or more characters, followed by a possible space (`\\s`) and another possible string of 1 or more characters.

## EDIT:

What if you have multiple numbers in one line?

In this case, I think the best option is to break each element and then apply a function to get the pattern you want. To exemplify I added another number on the first entry:

```
library(stringr)
vec <- c(" Sample Size =   955 95", " Importance      0.861", " Value      0.475 ")
vec_aux <- str_split(string = vec, pattern = " ")

f1 <- function(x) str_extract(string = x, pattern = "[0-9]{1,}(\\.)?[0-9]{0,}")
f2 <- function(x) str_extract(string = x, pattern = "[a-zA-Z]{1,}(\\s)?[a-zA-Z]{1,}")

out1 <- lapply(X = vec_aux, FUN = f1)
lapply(out1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])

[[1]]
[1] "955" "95" 

[[2]]
[1] "0.861"

[[3]]
[1] "0.475"

out2 <- lapply(X = vec_aux, FUN = f2)
lapply(out2, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])

[[1]]
[1] "Sample" "Size"  

[[2]]
[1] "Importance"

[[3]]
[1] "Value"
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for me! 

Your answer brought another questions though. What if i have multiple number within one line. That is:

vec <- c(" Sample Size =   955", " Importance      0.861 .641 .123", " Value      0.475  .512 .545 ")

If i use the first rule, only the first number (955, 0.861, 0.475) from each line will be extracted. If i modify a rule that would include the pattern three times (essentially cope and paste the rule one three times), i still get the same results. Any ideas?

Comment: I will improve the answer to show how to deal with this case.

Answer (score 1):

trim any whitespace off the ends, remove any equal sign and replace the last space with comma (or some other character if comma can appear).  Then read it in using `read.table`.  No packages are used.

```
read.table(text = sub("=", "", sub("(.*) ", "\\1,", trimws(x))), 
  sep = ",", as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
           V1      V2
1 Sample Size 955.000
2  Importance   0.861
3       Value   0.475
```

If `DF` is the resulting data frame then `DF$V1` and `DF$V2` are the two columns.